# Clustered BizTalk SSO configuration error

Tags: biztalk

While configuring the clustered SSO on the second server, I got an error, while running the command :

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On>ssoconfig
>   -restoresecret SSOSecret.bak Password : ******* Confirm Password : *******

The error is :

> Could not contact the SSO server ''. Check that SSO is
>   configured and that the SSO service is running on that server. (RPC:
>   0x800706D9: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint
>   mapper.)

The architecture is the following:

- A windows Failover Cluster, with two nodes, each with BizTalk Server
- A second Windows Failover Cluster, with two nodes, each with SQL Server. Always ON is on.

The SSO db belongs to an availibity group.

The error occurs when trying to restore the secret on the second node.
The SSO is installed on the SQL Server cluster. I configured the SSO (BizTalk configuration tool) on the two nodes. On the first, I created the SSO group, on the second I joined the group.

I configured the cluster resource by selecting the "Use Network Name for computer name", but I still have the same error while restoring the secret.

Comment: Have you already restored the secret at the second node?

Comment: The issue occurs when I try to restore the secret. So not yet.

Comment: The command you listed above is not restoring the secret, but backing it up. On which server are you running this? Also, if you start SSO Administration Console, do you see any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things you'll need to do at some point.

1. You run -restoresecret with the MSS running on that node.
2. The Enterprise Single Sign-On Service resource needs a dependent Network Name.
3. The Use Network Name as computer name box must be checked.

Comment: Thanks, it was the Use Network Name as computer name box. This step seems to be not mentioned in the MS documentation.

Comment: Yes. I had an over issue with SSO and DTC. It was about the secret. I mised a stage while configuring the server. All is fine now.